Unable to use variables with other css formats inside className
I'm trying to learn react and tailwind. On one of the tutorials, they have the code
<div className={'bg-black h-screen p-5 pt-8 ${open ? "w-72" : "w-20"}'}>

My problem is that when I copy this code, it doesn't function the way it is shown online. The ${open} part isn't showing up.
On the other hand, I have gotten
<div className={open ? "w-72" : "w-20"} />

to work. Am I able to combine the variables on top of the CSS into one line?
Thank you

For embedding variables inside strings you need to use back ticks, not single quotes. Check docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

wow. ok. I'm blind. Thank you so much
